# How to implement "Touch status bar to scroll to top" in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

situation : a tableView embeded in a scrollView

I have searched some questions, someone say that set the scrollView's scrollsToTop to NO ( scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO; ) will work . I tried , but it didn't work...

thanks for your help

EDIT...

I know the reason now
it is because I have more than one table view embeded in the scroll view
so I should set all other views except the one I'm in to "scrollsToTop = NO;"  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `scrollsToTop` to `NO` for the parent scroll view, and setting it to `YES` for the table view.

Comment: @joshz you probably have another visible TableView or ScrollView that has `scrollsToTop` set to `YES`.